# Taking multiple substrings from a single line in a .txt file in C#

Tags: c#, substring

Part of a class assignment I'm working on requires me to take isolate certain parts of a "students" info from a .txt file such as last name, first name, and gpa. While I can get the last name to appear properly, going beyond that is iffy, first names will be cut off or go to the middle initial seemingly randomly. I need help with having consistent cut off points based on markers (apostrophes) in the lines.

this is a sample of the .txt file Students2 which is located in the program's Bin Debug

```
(LIST (LIST 'Abbott 'Ashley 'J ) '8697387888 'ajabbott@mail.usi.edu 2.3073320999676614 )
(LIST (LIST 'Abbott 'Bradley 'M ) 'NONE 'bmabbott@mail.usi.edu 3.1915725161177115 )
(LIST (LIST 'Abbott 'Ryan 'T ) '8698689793 'rtabbott@mail.usi.edu 3.448215586562192 )
(LIST (LIST 'Abel 'Heather 'M ) '8698689386 'hmabel@mail.usi.edu 3.2517764202656974 )
```

Hopefully what I meant by markers makes sense, and the info is fake if anyone wondered.

The following is my current code, some of which was provided in an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication61
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StreamReader inFile;
        string inLine;

        if (File.Exists("Students2.txt"))
        {
            try
            {



                using (StreamWriter Malachi = File.AppendText("Students2.txt"))
                {
                    Malachi.WriteLine("(LIST (LIST 'Constant 'Malachi 'J ) '1832878847 'mconstant@mail.usi.edu 4.0000000000000000 )");
                }

                inFile = new StreamReader("Students2.txt");
                while ((inLine = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    int start = inLine.IndexOf("'");
                    if (start >= 0)
                    {
                        inLine = inLine.Substring(start);
                        int end = inLine.IndexOf(" ");
                        string lastname = inLine.Substring(0, end);
                        int endTwo = inLine.IndexOf(" ");
                        string firstname = inLine.Substring(end, endTwo);
                        int endThree = inLine.IndexOf(" ");
                        string email = inLine.Substring(endTwo, endThree);
                        Console.WriteLine( lastname + firstname );

                    }
                }
            }


            catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Again I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in regards to cutting off at specific points. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not just split the string based on ' and use array index to get values?

Comment: It seems you think that `inLine.IndexOf(" ");` gives different results when you call it repeatedly on the same string/line. Why would you think so? Please verify your assumptions by reading the documentation of `string.IndexOf()` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_) and spend some time observing what your code does in the debugger ([Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger))

Comment: It's an interesting problem (particularly since I worked in Lisp for two years way back in the late 90s).  I believe the nested lists precludes using regular expressions, and it will also make a simple "look for markers" strategy very complicated.  I think you will need a simple recursive parser (that recognizes three types, Lists, strings (that start with apostrophes) and numbers (that don't).

Answer (score 2):

you can use the split function and replace function to get what you are looking for something like this

```
    string test = "(LIST (LIST 'Constant 'Malachi 'J ) '1832878847 'mconstant@mail.usi.edu 4.0000000000000000 )";

    test = test.Replace(")","");

    string[] abc = test.Split(new string[] { "'" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    Console.WriteLine("Last Name =" + abc[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("First Name =" + abc[2]);
    Console.WriteLine("Middle Initial =" + abc[3]);
    Console.WriteLine("Email gpa =" + abc[abc.Length-1]);
```

**UPDATE**

In case there is no apostrophe for gpa you can get those values as below, just replace the last line with this

```
    Console.WriteLine("Email =" + (abc[abc.Length-1]).Split(' ')[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("gpa =" + (abc[abc.Length-1]).Split(' ')[1]);
```

Here is a fiddle for it https://dotnetfiddle.net/vJYLXW

Comment: Well, that's a lot simpler than what I was thinking about - but not as general.  +1 to you!

Comment: Unfortunatelly your code gives incorrect email address.

Comment: @Pati Your string doesn't have a apostrophe to differentiate between email and gpa if that's the case I have updated the fiddle accordingly

Answer (score 1):

you need to update inLine every time you take off substring like -

```
int start = inLine.IndexOf("'");
                    if (start >= 0)
                    {
                        inLine = inLine.Substring(start);
                        int end = inLine.IndexOf(" ");
                        string lastname = inLine.Substring(0, end);
                        inLine = inLine.Substring(end + 1);
                        int endTwo = inLine.IndexOf(" ");
                        string firstname = inLine.Substring(end, endTwo);
                        inLine = inLine.Substring(endTwo + 1);
                        int endThree = inLine.IndexOf(" ");
                        string email = inLine.Substring(endTwo, endThree);
                        .
                        .

                    }
```

and so on.....

OR you take find next space after end point of first string like this -

```
int start = inLine.IndexOf("'");
            if (start >= 0)
            {
                inLine = inLine.Substring(start);
                int end = inLine.IndexOf(" ");
                string lastname = inLine.Substring(0, end);
                int endTwo = inLine.IndexOf(' ', end + 1);
                string firstname = inLine.Substring(end, endTwo - end);
                int endThree = inLine.IndexOf(' ', endTwo + 1);
                string middleinitial = inLine.Substring(endTwo, endThree - endTwo);
                endThree += 2; // to escape ')' after middle initial
                int endFour = inLine.IndexOf(' ', endThree + 1);
                string phone = inLine.Substring(endThree, endFour - endThree);
                int endFive = inLine.IndexOf(' ', endFour + 1);
                string email = inLine.Substring(endFour, endFive - endFour);
                int endSix = inLine.IndexOf(' ', endFive + 1);
                string gpa = inLine.Substring(endFive, endSix - endFive);
                Console.WriteLine("Last Name - " + lastname);
                Console.WriteLine("First Name - " + firstname);
                Console.WriteLine("Middle Initial - " + middleinitial);
                Console.WriteLine("Phone - " + phone);
                Console.WriteLine("Email - " + email);
                Console.WriteLine("GPA - " + gpa);
            }
```

But I would recommend string split option. Read about [String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
 while ((inLine = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var splits = inLine.Split(new[] { ' ', '\'' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (splits.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Last Name - " + splits[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("First Name - " + splits[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Middle Initial - " + splits[4]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Phone - " + splits[6]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Email - " + splits[7]);
                    Console.WriteLine("GPA - " + splits[8]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------");
            }
```

Comment: Using the second suggestion it does this:                                                               
    'Abbott 'Ashley 'J ) ' 'J ) '8697387888  ) '8697387888 'ajab '8697387888 
    'ajabbott@mail.usi.                                                                                                        At this point, I've tried to print the GPA but as you can see the middle initial repeats along with the phone number

Comment: In order to separate every element you need few adjustments. [Check here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/abfei9).

Comment: Also if you need to remove apostrophes from each element, you'll need further adjustments. String.split method is pretty straight forward and you can take out all the sub parts easily.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier  to get the desired fields with regexp:

```
Regex rPattern= new Regex(@"\'([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+\)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)");

....

Match m = rPattern.Match(inLine );

if(m.Success)                     
{                        

    string lastname = m.Groups[1].Value;                        
    string firstname = m.Groups[2].Value;                        
    string middlename = m.Groups[3].Value;                        
    string phone = m.Groups[4].Value;                        
    string email = m.Groups[5].Value;                        
    string somenumber = m.Groups[6].Value;                         
}
```

Your code can be something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
//PTK: don't forget include following line. IT'S IMPORTANT !!!
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication61
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StreamReader inFile;
        string inLine;

        //PTK: patern for your fields
        Regex rPattern= new Regex(@"\'([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+\)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)[\'\s]+([^'\s]+)");

        if (File.Exists("Students2.txt"))
        {
            try
            {



                using (StreamWriter Malachi = File.AppendText("Students2.txt"))
                {
                    Malachi.WriteLine("(LIST (LIST 'Constant 'Malachi 'J ) '1832878847 'mconstant@mail.usi.edu 4.0000000000000000 )");
                }

                inFile = new StreamReader("Students2.txt");
                while ((inLine = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                 //PTK: match the current line with the pattern
                 Match m = rPattern.Match(inLine );


                 if(m.Success)
                 {

                    string lastname = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    string firstname = m.Groups[2].Value;
                    string middlename = m.Groups[3].Value;
                    string phone = m.Groups[4].Value;
                    string email = m.Groups[5].Value;
                    string somenumber = m.Groups[6].Value;

                    Console.WriteLine( lastname + firstname );
                 }


                }
            }


            catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can see working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FrU4l5